# Cloud9 give the editor window focus

Tags: ide, focus, keyboard-shortcuts, cloud9-ide

Within the [Cloud9 IDE](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/), if the focus is set to the Files sidebar (toggleable via <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>), how does one refocus on the editor window to continue coding without reverting to using the mouse?

My current workaround is to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> for `go to line {n}`, but this adds unnecessary steps and can lead to the page scrolling to a completely different location than currently working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no shortcut for this.
But it is easy to add with user script

```
var editors = require("ext/editors/editors");
require("ext/commands/commands").addCommand({
    name: "focusEditor",
    exec:function() {
        if (editors.currentEditor)
            editors.currentEditor.focus();
    },
    bindKey: "ctrl-alt-w"
});
```

if you can think of a good shortcut for this suggest it on https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/issues/2032#issuecomment-9427700 too

Comment: great, thanks Ace guru. I had been starting to edit through the source today by cloning most places the gotoline was referenced but ended up making a mess, I'll pop this in. Will add a suggestion, either for the shortcut alone, or together with callbacks on hide menus, like when closing the files sidebar, automatic focus should be given to the editor or previous main focus area.

Comment: also, this works a treat and my mouse thanks you for the vacation time!